# Sorting in Java/Selenium/html

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, wait

This is Java, Selenium and Chrome though it must work for IE and Firefox too,

I am writing an automation script to verify a web page.  Part of the page is a table with columns such as

```
" Name[ud]   Dept[ud]   Date[ud]   Status[ud] ..."
```

with thousands of rows of data.

The [ud] are actually up and down arrows that appear when you hover over the columns, so if you click one it sorts that column ascending or descending.  After I click, I get the column of values into a list, make a sorted copy of the list and compare them.  This works sometimes.  The data takea while to sort. Here are the three scenarios

1) The sort happens quickly enough so that when I get the values, they are already sorted and the test works.

2) The sort takes a while so when I get the values they are still the pre-sorted values in which case the test is invalid.

3) The sort is partially done by the time I get the values resulting in an eventual stale element.

The management here frowns on doing a Thread.sleep(milliseconds) and I am not sure what a good time would be anyway.  I can't find any xpath I can wait for because the paths are there before and after the sort.  I am looking for a way to wait till the sort is done. Any suggestions.  Any suggestions?  The only thing I can notice is that the cursor spins while the sort is being done. Can Selenium perhaps be told to wait for the cursor to stop spinning?

Answer (score 0):

See Implicit and Explicit waits in Selenium's WebDriver. You'll want an Explicit Wait.

Basically, you can wait until the WebElement representing your table is available to the browser.

Link: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

you can use Thread.sleep(10000); here it will wait for 10 secs.
Or you can add implicit waits.

Comment: OP says management frown on Thread.sleep(), and implicit waiting won't help as WebDriver may throw an exception (or return null) if the sort operation takes longer than the specified implicit wait time.

Comment: you can specify any amount of time in implicit wait. You can also add condition to wait any particualr element to present or to be visible

Comment: Yes, you can set any amount of time, but how would OP know how much time to wait without being inefficient? Also, waiting for elements to be present/visible/clickable is an explicit wait, not implicit.

Comment: Or you can wait for ajax request to complete

Comment: Again, that's an explicit wait, not implicit.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** You can **wait for the spinning cursor to appear first**(`just in case it takes time to appear`) and **then wait for it to disappear**. You can use [Explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for both purposes. Please use the below codes;

**1- After Clicking, wait for spinner to appear using the below code:**

```
try
{
    // Waits for 10 seconds so that the cursor appears
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    // Wait until the cursor is located on the page
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//xpath of the cursor")));
    System.out.println("Waiting ends ... Cursor Appeared in the page.");
}
catch (Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error came while waiting for Cursor to Appear : " +e.getMessage());
}
```

**2- Wait for spinner to Disappear using the below code:**

```
try
{
    // Waits for 30 seconds so that the cursor disappear
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    // Wait until the cursor disappears from the page
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//xpath of the cursor")));
    System.out.println("Waiting ends ... Cursor disappeared from the page.");
}
catch (Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error came while waiting for Cursor to Disappear : " +e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Implicit wait or Fluent Wait which is available in Selenium Webdriver.